# Изменение содержимого JFrame в Java

Tags: java, swing

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
     JPanel leftPane = new JPanel();
     JPanel rightPane = new JPanel();
     public NavigatorPanel navigatorPanel = new NavigatorPanel(this);

    public MainFrame() throws Exception {
        ...
        leftPane.add(navigatorPanel);
        rightPane.setLayout(new CardLayout());
        ...
    }

    public void changeTab(String panelName) {
       ...
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ...
    }
}

// Содержимое класса с панелью
public class NavigatorPanel extends JPanel {
    private MainFrame frame;
public NavigatorPanel(MainFrame frame) {
    try {
        this.frame = frame; //Сообщаем ссылку на искомый фрейм.
        jbInit(); //Запускаем выполнение содержимого JPanel
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Подскажите, как правильно вызвать из панели **navigatorPanel**, расположенной в отдельном классе, выполнение метода **changeTab** в текущем фрейме.

По сути метод потом будет менять содержимое панели rightPanel.

**Дополнено.**
Пытаюсь передать вот так: Main.getFrame().changeTab("NOTES");
Тут было содержимое класса Main

**Дополнено1.**
Код обновлён на правильный.
Далее просто в нужном месте NavigatorPanel прописываем frame.changeTab() и будет счастье.

Comment: я бы неудержался и впихнул листенер:

    public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements NavigationListener {...}
    public interface NavigationListener 
    {
       void navigateTo(String destination);
    }

Comment: Ок, буду иметь ввиду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передайте вашему navigatorPanel ссылку на MainFrame

Comment: Пытаюсь передать вот так:
<pre><code>Main.getFrame().changeTab("NOTES");

//Содержимое Main
public class Main {
 static MainFrame frame = null;
 
 public static MainFrame getFrame() {
  return frame;
 }
 
}</code></pre>


Возникает ошибка
<pre><code>Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ru.wolq.gui.NavigatorPanel.actionPerformed(NavigatorPanel.java:71)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
</code></pre>

Как правильно передавать ссылку?

Comment: У вас же явно написано `static MainFrame frame = null;` Поэтому `getFrame()` и возвращает null.